# user interface for selenium with specflow c#

Tags: c#, selenium, user-interface, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

my end goal is to have my boss (not a technical person) use the testing software on her own.(without visual studio or any other 3rd party software) So, i need to build a user interface. here is what one of my scenarios look like. scentially have this scenario run in a console( I can figure out the UI later) or have the HTML report that specflows generates done without visual studio.
I also need the user to pick which scenario runs.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using static Aflutter3.Element_objects.Element;
using static Aflutter3.Element_objects;
using static Aflutter3.Other_Functions;
using static Aflutter3.Login_Class;

namespace Aflutter3

{
[Binding]
public class SigninSteps
{


    [Given(@"I open google chrome")]
    public void GivenIOpenGoogleChrome()
    {
        if (Driver != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Opened");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessfully Opened");

    }

    [Given(@"I go to aflutter sign in page")]
    public void GivenIGoToAflutterSignInPage()
    {

        if (Go_To_LoginPage() == true)
        Console.WriteLine("Website successfully Accessed");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Website unsuccessfully Accessed");

    }

    [Given(@"I enter the username and password")]
    public void GivenIEnterTheUsernameAndPassword()
    {

                Enter_Credentials();
                Console.WriteLine("Username and password successfully entered");


    }

    [When(@"i click sign in")]
    public void WhenIClickSignIn()
    {
            Click_Sign_in();
            Console.WriteLine("Login To Aflutter Button Successfully Clicked");


    }

    [Then(@"I should be in the homepage")]
    public void ThenIShouldBeInTheHomepage()
    {
        if (Check_If_Homepage_Loaded())
            Console.WriteLine("Homepage was succesfully loaded");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Homepage was unsuccesfully loaded");


    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is..

Comment: It would be best to use the Stackoverflow platform to ask specific questions and not expect someone to create a working project for you.

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a one file, which will go through the all flow - start tests, generate report, maybe open report. It can be cmd file or power-shell script. When this script is executed, all happens and you boss needs only to check report.